# Uninstallation of application

Tags: c#

i have developed an application in C# which contains the facility of uninstallation. My primary requirement is that when user uninstall the application befor uninstallation start i want to call webservice which perform some operations.

I have return code for this but it works only when user uninstalls application through option given in programms menu. But it not works in the case of uninstallation from Control panel.

how can i do this?
thanks.

Comment: How are you developing your installer?  Wix provides that sort of functionality.

Comment: I have used MSI for developing installer. and added following code added in  program.cs  string[] arguments=Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();foreach (string argument in arguments){if (argument.Split('=')[0].ToLower() == "/u"){ string guid = argument.Split('=')[1];
                       string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
                       ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "/msiexec.exe", "/qb/x " + guid);
                       Process.Start(si);
                       Application.Exit();
                   }
               }

Answer (score 0):

Is it an MSI?  If so you just need a custom action on uninstallation.

Have you triggered a special command line that is run when the user clicks the link in the programmes menu?  If so you should make this the "default" behaviour so that when it is executed from the control panel, it will work exactly the same way.

Comment: yes i have used the ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "/msiexec.exe", "/qb/x " + guid); Process.Start(si); this command line what next i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an MSI you can try to use a custom action on uninstallation , you can follow how it is done here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx

Then overide

```
  public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
  {
       base.Uninstall(savedState);
      //you code goes here that does any uninstall stuff
  }
```

This will run when you run uninstall from control panel

Comment: i have don this but i am getting error 1001 and my application doesnot uninstall. What i want is that befor uninstallation process iwant to run some function from my application so how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Setup Project's Custom Action. Here is a tutorial

[How to Add Custom Action to Visual Studio Setup Project](http://hackermini.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-add-custom-action-to-visual.html)